# Are there privacy risks in sharing the MacOS .DS_Store files?

Tags: privacy, macos

In MacOS, each folder has a hidden `.DS_Store` file. If I compress a folder on MacOS, the zip file will contain those `.DS_Store` files. What information is contained in those files, and does it expose any information about me, my device, my other files, etc?

Comment: Have you looked this up? I mean, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) has good info. I googled "Are there privacy risks in sharing the MacOS .DS_Store files?" and got more good info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you have specifically included private information in those files, then no, it usually not considered a privacy risk to share them.

[.DS_Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) files contain metadata attributes that Finder want to store, but cannot store directly for each file or directory (for example if the file system does not support such attributes). This is typically things such as the (x,y)-coordinates of the file icon (i.e. if you move them around in the Finder window), colored tags if you apply those, custom icons you might have chosen for files, etc.

Note for others: The .DS_Store file can contain names of files and subfolders in this particular folder, which you might consider private. For this particular question, those files and subfolders are included in the compressed archive to be shared, so they aren't private.

Comment: .DS_Store files do contain the names of the subfolders. This may be private information.

Comment: Not really - he is specifically stating that he is sharing the folder including contents (Such as subfolders) - so if he's already sharing it, it's not private.

Comment: You're quite right. I meant that sharing just the .DS_Store file could be a privacy risk.